# Gitolite - Perhaps submodules can help me out

Tags: git, git-submodules, gitolite

actually I don't have a lot experience with GIT and I've been using gitolite to create and manage some repositories, but now, I need to create a repository and then inside that repository others.

The idea is manage repositories and users, create one repository called MAIN, and then inside this repository create other where just one team has access to make changes, like:

- MAIN

  - TEAM1
  - TEAM2
  - TEAM3
    ...
  - TEAM999

But when I clone the MAIN repository I want have access to all content.

That's make sense? Is it possible? How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify:

- an account/group with access to `@all` repos: that will be enough for a `git clone MAIN`, followed by a `git submodule update --init --recursive` to be able to clone everything.
  See [special group @all](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/groups.html).
- accounts/group with access only to their specific repos.

Comment: I see.. but the problems here is I have more repos like MAIN, it isn't just one, MAIN is one of the projects I have it... so if I make a group police specifying access for @all, they'll have access a everything...

And, where I have to use the command about submodules, I've been using Gitolite, and now I'm a little confuse if the admin of the repo has to do or somebody else...

Sorry, but it's my first time with this tool...

Comment: @user3735246 but isn't it what you want? That a select group of users have access to all repos, in order to clone all the MAINs repos and their submodules?

Comment: @user3735246 if not, you would need to define a group of repos for each MAIN and their respective submodules.

Comment: actually what I want is manage the one repository and when I clone the main all repos (all teams) come recursively. That's exactly what I want.

Comment: @user3735246 so I maintain my answer: those who clone `MAIN` need to have access to all submodules repos. Either `@all` or `@agroup` (representing all `MAIN` submodules)